# replacing values in a cell array for matching values from another

Tags: matlab, match, cell-array

There is a `cell` array in MATLAB

```
B = 

    [ 1708]    [ 2392]    '+'
    [ 3394]    [ 3660]    '+'
    [ 5490]    [ 5743]    '+'
    [ 7555]    [ 7809]    '-'
    [ 9256]    [ 9509]    '-'
    [12878]    [15066]    '-'
    [16478]    [17458]    '-'
```

and another `cell` array

C =

```
[4]
[7]
[1]
[6]
[2]
[5]
[3]
```

I want to replace the values in `C` with the values in `B{...,3}` such that `C` becomes

```
C = 

    '-'
    '-'
    '+'
    '-'
    '+'
    '-'
    '+'
```

How can I do that in MATLAB? I currently did this but got error

```
>> C(C == 'x') = B
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Comment: post the code, what are the errors you are getting ?

Comment: I don't understand your code sample. Why are you comparing to `x`?

Comment: x is the row index of B

Comment: It makes no sense to compare to the char `'x'`, at least following your problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
C = cellfun(@(x)B(x,3),C);
```

This addresses the problem you were seeing with `C` no longer being a cell array - note the subtle difference between `B{}` and `B()`.

Comment: That made C a 7x1 char, I need to keep it as a Cell array

Comment: Use NUM2CELL around it. It would be - C = num2cell(cellfun(@(x)B{x,3},C));

Comment: @Divakar, please don't edit someone else's answer, even if you have a better suggestion. Leave a comment, and let the person who answered edit it if he/she feels like it. (You may edit to make it readable, typos, formatting etc., but not the content).

Comment: @ Robert, I am still learning the etiquette of commenting here! Thanks @Floris.

Comment: @chris see my update. Replacing the `{}` with `()` fixed the problem you were seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Horizontal concatenation ([`[]`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html)) with [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) cell array output (`{:}`) gives a direct way to index the appropriate rows in `B`:

```
Cnew = B([C{:}],3)
```

Comment: I like this approach.

Comment: One-liners aren't very helpful without a little explanation... now for some links.

Answer (score 1):

Basic indexing, to get the elements of `X` in the order `a=[1,3,2,4]` use `X(a)`. Indices are matrices, thus a conversion is needed, nothing else.

```
B(cell2mat(c),3)
```